# What do I need to do in preparation for cloning a django repository?

Tags: django, git, postgresql

Assuming the django project repository is on github and I have had no interaction with it previously.
So: I cd to a new directory on my computer.
I clone the repository.
If the django project is using postgresql, do I have to have postgresql installed on my local machine?
  Do I have to be running in a virtual environment to use a specific interpreter?

Thanks Peter

Answer (score 0):

**Database**
You can actually use another database on your local copy if you choose, although in general it's a good idea to use the same database locally.

If you're going to be using postgres locally, yes you'll need to install it and then create your local database. Once you have your local database setup, you'll need to change some config values of your `DATABASES` property in settings.

**Packages**
Your project will also have some dependencies which should be listed in a requirements.txt file at the root directory. If it is not, you'll need to find out which packages need to be installed via `pip freeze` in the production console.

**Virtual Env**
You should use a virtual environment, but it's not completely necessary to get your project up and running. Virtualenvs allow you to have different installs and runtimes for different projects.

**Other**
Every project is different, and there will most likely be some other things that pop up. However, this should get you going in the right direction.